# cmake Could NOT find LibXml2 (missing: LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR)

Tags: cmake, libxml2

I have some software from a collaborator.  When performing >cmake .. I receive the error message "Could NOT find LibXml2 (missing: LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR)" (see screenshot)

I have found the libxml2.so.2.9.12 file on my machine and have added its directory to my PATH (/home/silicon/anaconda3/pkgs/libxml2-2.9.12-h03d6c58_0/lib) as well as several others that seem related, including one that just had a link to the file in it.

I saw a similar question in here (although on a Windows machine), here:  [cmake cannot find LibXml2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41897622/cmake-cannot-find-libxml2)
and I have tried several versions of this, but still the same error.  I typed in the path the way it would look on a Linux machine (parenthesis in previous paragraph).  I tried several versions.  Always the same error.

I looked in the CMakeLists.txt file to see if there was something that looked like I could adjust it for my system, but I don't know anything about that type of file and I just left it the way it was.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: The variable `LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR` denotes the **directory** where **header files** of libxml2 are located. E.g. under this directory should be a file `libxml/xpath.h`.

Comment: Try setting `-DLibXml2_ROOT=/home/silicon/anaconda3/pkgs/libxml2-2.9.12-h03d6c58_0` at the CMake command line.

Comment: Thank you for the response!

After getting some help from my collaborator I fixed this by using "sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev" and it cleared up after that.

I have a different, similar problem now with some other thing it's not finding, but this specific problem seems to be clear now.

Comment: Please consider adding the solution as an answer to your own question instead of just putting it in a comment.

Answer (score 4):

Quick solution from the asker's comment: **sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev**